# CGRectZero vs CGRect.zeroRect?

Tags: swift, struct, cgrect, cgrectmake

Both seem to work the same in Swift. Which should we use?

1. `CGRectZero` vs `CGRect.zeroRect`
2. `GRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1)` vs `CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 1, height: 1)`
   `UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)` vs `UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)`
3. Other patterns

Answer (score 74):

#### UPDATE<sup>2</sup>

In Swift 3, `CGRectZero` is no longer available. `CGRect.zero` is your only choice. [Learn it, know it, live it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8E7_u2qgjE)

#### UPDATE

`CGRect.zeroRect` was renamed to `CGRect.zero` in iOS 9.0. That is close enough to `CGRectZero` (and the same number of keystrokes, counting <kbd>shift</kbd> as a keystroke) that I'd recommend `CGRect.zero` to anyone who's not an Objective-C coder in the habit of using `CGRectZero`.

#### ORIGINAL

There's no particular reason to favor one or the other. You should use whichever style you or your team prefers.

Personally, I'd use `CGRectZero` because it's shorter and I'm used to it from Objective-C.

I'd go with `CGRectMake` for the same reason.

I'd probably use `UIEdgeInsets(top:left:bottom:right:)` because I rarely see instances of `UIEdgeInsets`, so I'm less likely to remember the order of the arguments in `UIEdgeInsetsMake`. (You get placeholders for it when you're typing in a call to `UIEdgeInsetsMake`, but when you're reading existing code there's no hints about the argument order.)

Comment: `CGRectZero` is legacy - all you need to use is `.zero` in Swift2

Comment: You cannot always omit the type: `var rect = .zero` will not work.

Comment: yes, because the type is unknown. `let rect = CGRect.zero` works fine

Comment: `let rect: CGRect = .zero` works like a charm too if you really want to get crazy